# PayPal Express Checkout with credit card payment and future payments

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I currently have a system in place utilizing the Express Checkout SOAP API to complete a customer's e-commerce checkout. Imagine a subscription service. I provide the option of a one-time purchase via DoExpressCheckoutPayment as well as the option to conduct application-triggered monthly payments via DoReferenceTransactionRequest (I wanted more control which is why I did not go the route of CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile). Now I would like to allow guest checkout, while also maintaining the ability to perform monthly payments.

In testing I:

1. Verified that guest checkout was allowed in the PayPal account UI
2. Set SolutionType = Sole
3. Set LandingPage = Billing

But I was unsuccessful in getting the guest checkout option.

HOWEVER, I noticed that by changing BillingCodeType from MERCHANTINITIATEDBILLING to NONE solved my issue. But if I changed the billing code type to none and checked out as a guest, the future monthly payments would fail due to not having a billing agreement.

I haven't found an obvious answer to my exact question but based on bits of documentation that I've found it's seeming like the billing agreement is required. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You can't call DoExpressCheckoutPayment a month later.  You would have to be using DoReferenceTransaction and including a billing agreement in the Express Checkout flow.  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: @AndrewAngell you are absolutely right! I misspoke in the original comment. Updating...

Comment: In that case, guest checkout won't work when you're including a billing agreement.  If you want to work with credit cards directly (and reference transactions using credit card authorizations/sales) you'll need to add Payments Pro to your PayPal account.